# Change python default compiler to MSC

Tags: python, package, compiler-construction, msys2

I earlier had python installed from python.org ( MSC). Recently I installed MSYS2 and by default, python has installed again (GCC). If I check my python version in command prompt I will get this :

"Python 3.10.9 (main, Jan 14 2023, 21:23:14)  [GCC 12.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32".

How to switch back to MSC ?

Edit :- After adding path in Environment variable ,I managed to solve it

Comment: What do you mean by default compiler? Are you compiling CPython yourself? Are you writing a CPython extension module?

Comment: No, I just want my python to be in MSC instead of GCC

Comment: What do you mean by "be in MSC"?

Comment: check PATH and PYTHONHOME, maybe PYTHONPATH variable in Windows, make sure they're pointed to correct location.

Comment: I would like to have this :
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:37:02) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 

But currently I am getting this :
"Python 3.10.9 (main, Jan 14 2023, 21:23:14) [GCC 12.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32".

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish? The version info you're looking at has to do with how Python was compiled _on the machine that built it_. Unless you're compiling Python yourself, that version info has no relationship to your computer. There's usually no reason to care about what compiler was used to compile your interpreter.

Comment: @Brian he has 2 python installed, one Windows native(built by MSC) and another from MSYS2(built by GCC). Obviously no way to switch compiler for a given interpreter but seems that he is trying to invoke the Windows python.exe instead of the one in MSYS2.